# restrict certain table to be viewed by a particular user in mysql

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a user in mysql that I have granted all access to a particular database. However I do not want him/her to see a few tables in the database. How do I do so? I tried configuring via phpmyadmin, but the best I can see is this:

[image]

But I don't see any option to hide/restrict this user to see a particualr table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might try something like REVOKE ALL ON selectedDatabase.desiredTable FROM 'joe_blow'@'%'

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/revoke.html

Comment: I am getting the following error upon invoking the command #1141 - There is no such grant defined for user